# How to create a chart on the same worksheet using a for loop statement?

Tags: vba, excel, loops, charts

```
Name       Progress  
Student1    93    
Student2    80
Student3    51
Student4    91
Student5    65
Student6    45          
student7    33
```

I am still new to VBA programming. Above is my data set example and below is my code which is able to populate columns C to E to the right without giving any error. Below is my chart code which gives me a bad chart when I run it. Please advise on how to go about plotting these populated values on columns C to E on a bar chart on the same worksheet, where a green bar shows progress >= 90, amber bar shows 50 <= Progress And Progress < 90 and red bar shows progress <50.

```
Sub ClassCategories()

    Dim startRow As Long, lastRow As Long, n As Integer
    startRow = 2
    n = 8
    Dim i As Long, Progress As Long
    Dim sClass1 As String
    Dim sClass2 As String
    Dim sClass3 As String

    For i = startRow To n
        Progress = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value
        ' Check progress and classify accordingly
        If Progress >= 90 Then
            sClass3 = Progress
        Else
            sClass3 = " "
        End If

        If 50 <= Progress And Progress < 90 Then
            sClass2 = Progress
        Else
            sClass2 = " "
        End If

        If Progress < 50 Then
            sClass1 = Progress
        Else
            sClass1 = " "
        End If

        ' Write out the class to column C to E
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = sClass1
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = sClass2
        Worksheets("sheet1").Range("E" & i).Value = sClass3
    Next
End Sub
```

Private Sub Createachart()

```
    Dim oChObj As ChartObject, rngSourceData As Range, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set rngSourceData = ws.Range("C3:E8")

    Set oChObj = ws.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ws.Columns("A").Left,     
    Width:=290, Top:=ws.Rows(8).Top, Height:=190)



        With oChObj.Chart

             .ChartType = xlColumnClustered

             .SetSourceData Source:=rngSourceData, PlotBy:=xlColumns

             .Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames = ws.Range("A2:A8")

             .HasTitle = True
        End With


   End Sub
```

Comment: Record a macro. Then adjust where needed

Comment: please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You're halfway there, but the code you have presently doesn't show any effort towards creating a chart, so it reads like you expect someone to provide a full solution for you. Please try to solve the problem on your own and revise your question so that it states a *specific*, answerable problem or error you need help to resolve.

Comment: So, should we create chart for you?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include my chart macro.

Comment: You want to plot it on the same chart?

Comment: Yes, same on the same worksheet if I do follow your question, where the Createachart macro is able to read off the macro that populate values on the columns C to E. At the moment, the Createachart macro can only able to read off and plot the values if I do put the values manually, which is the opposite of what i want. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: Could you visualize what you wanna get? I barely understand how the chart should look like...

Comment: I want a bar chart graph where a student 6  goes with a bar = 45 %, student7  goes with a bar = 33 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code is what you need (providing your example table starts in A1 cell):

```
Sub CreateChart()
    
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim lColor&, i%, x, arr
    
    '// Remove all charts
    For Each sh In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoChart Then sh.Delete
    Next
    
    '// Add chart to sheet
    With Range("A10:N30")
        Set ch = .Parent.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumn, .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height).Chart
    End With
    
    With ch
    
        '// If user's selection is within chart data range,
        '// then Excel will create chart based on data in this range.
        '// We don't need it, so clear the chart out.
        .ChartArea.ClearContents
        
        '// Add series
        Set ser = ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
        ser.Values = Range("B2:B8").Value
        ser.XValues = Range("A2:A8").Value
        
        '// Get values
        arr = ser.Values
        
        '// Format points based on values
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            x = arr(i)
            Select Case True
                Case x >= 90: lColor = vbGreen
                Case x >= 50 And x < 90: lColor = vbYellow
                Case x < 50: lColor = vbRed
            End Select
            ser.Points(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = lColor
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

You can download workbook with code [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvqfUD6Rp0UCjmAFnhVJ7vCMIuQf).

#### Result:

[image: IMG1]

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate your help JohnyL. You helped me to look at the problem differently i.e. using one column range instead of using three column range than I had previously thought. I will continue to learn to learn VBA on my own so that tomorrow I can also contribute in helping others.